# How to retrive a particular data in the sqlite database in android?

Tags: android

I am having an error in my logcat.
Here

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table japanesebaybayin already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE japanesebaybayin (_id INTEGER, language_japaneseTEXT, language_japaneseeaTEXT, language_tagalogTEXT, language_definitionTEXT);
```

Can somebody help me to find the correct solution for this? I cannot retrieve a particular row in the database.

This is my code:

```
public class TranslationActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

protected SQLiteDatabase db;
protected EditText txtenglishAplha;
protected TextView tvdefinition;
protected TextView tvtagalog;
public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
public static final String KEY_JAPANESE="language_japanese";
public static final String KEY_JAPANESEEA="language_japaneseea";
public static final String KEY_TAGALOG="language_tagalog";
public static final String KEY_DEFINITION="language_definition";

private final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
private final String DATABASE_TABLE = "japanesebaybayin";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.translation_main);

    db =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
    //      DATABASE_TABLE +
    //      " (rowid INTEGER, japancharacter VARCHAR," +
    //      " japanalphabet VARCHAR, tagalog VARCHAR, " + 
    //      " definition VARCHAR);");

    db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER, "+ 
            KEY_JAPANESE + "TEXT, " +
            KEY_JAPANESEEA + "TEXT, " +
            KEY_TAGALOG + "TEXT, " +
            KEY_DEFINITION + "TEXT);"
    );

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            DATABASE_TABLE +
            " Values (1,'\u3042\u308A\u304C\u3068\u3046','arigato','salamat','giving thanks');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            DATABASE_TABLE +
            " Values (2,'\u3042\u308A\u304C\u3068\u3046','sayonara','paalam','giving goodbye');");

     //Buttons
    Button btnsearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);
    btnsearch.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Edit Texts
    txtenglishAplha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtenglishAlpha);
    txtenglishAplha.requestFocus();

    //Text Views
    tvdefinition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdefinition);
    tvtagalog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtagalog);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.translation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String tagalog="", definition="", japanalpha;
    Cursor cursor;
    switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.btnsearch:

         japanalpha = txtenglishAplha.getText().toString();
         String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_JAPANESEEA, KEY_TAGALOG, KEY_DEFINITION};
            cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_JAPANESEEA + "='"+japanalpha+"'", null, null, null, null);

         //String qjoiner = "SELECT japanalphabet, tagalog, definition from " +DATABASE_TABLE+ " where japanalphabet ='"+japanalpha+"';";
         //Log.i("-----search table joiner----- ",qjoiner);
        // cursor=db.rawQuery(qjoiner, null);
         if(cursor != null){
             cursor.moveToFirst();
             tagalog = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TAGALOG)).toString();
             definition = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION)).toString();
             tvtagalog.setText(tagalog);
             tvdefinition.setText(definition);
         }else{
                 tvtagalog.setText(tagalog);
                 tvdefinition.setText(definition);
         }

    break;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table creation query is wrong. See the below image. I am working to get the solution.

[image]

here is the code which you want.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Test extends Activity {


protected SQLiteDatabase db;
public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
public static final String KEY_JAPANESE="language_japanese";
public static final String KEY_JAPANESEEA="language_japaneseea";
public static final String KEY_TAGALOG="language_tagalog";
public static final String KEY_DEFINITION="language_definition";
private final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
private final String DATABASE_TABLE = "japanesebaybayin";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);    
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + "  INTEGER, "+ 
                KEY_JAPANESE + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_JAPANESEEA + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_TAGALOG + "  TEXT, " + 
                KEY_DEFINITION + " TEXT);" // the wrong which you made is here there was no space between column name and type. 
        );

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                DATABASE_TABLE +
                " Values (1,'\u3042\u308A\u304C\u3068\u3046','arigato','salamat','giving thanks');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                DATABASE_TABLE +
                " Values (2,'\u3042\u308A\u304C\u3068\u3046','sayonara','paalam','giving goodbye');");





        Cursor mCursor = null;

        try {
            mCursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM japanesebaybayin where language_japaneseea='arigato'", null);
            // you can change it above query with dynamic inputs. 


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(mCursor != null){
            mCursor.moveToFirst();

            mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION)).toString();

             System.out.println(" 1111 " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TAGALOG)).toString());
             System.out.println(" 222 " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_JAPANESEEA)).toString());
             System.out.println(" 333 " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_JAPANESE)).toString());
             System.out.println(" 444 " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION)).toString());


        }  


}


}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this image. I add space to my code just by now. BUt i am having another problem again and this according to my logcat. Here: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: language_japaneseea (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT language_japaneseea, language_tagalog, language_definition FROM japanesebaybayin WHERE language_japaneseea='arigato'; Can you tell me what should I do to this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for your image.. It's finally working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to create your database table every time the activity/fragment starts.

You should only create it once as otherwise you will get the error you are getting stating that the table already exists.

You should read the documentation for [SqliteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) and use this as it separates your database code from your activity code and allows you to handles database updates etc cleanly.

Comment: Actually i already rename the DATABASE_TABLE twice but the same message was showing to my logcat. Can you help me what is the appropriate code for that?

Comment: Renaming your table will not work as you will simply hit the same issue again the next time the app starts. Read my answer, learn how to  use the SqliteOpenHelper and your issue will be resolved.

Comment: this is the another logcat message that I've encountered. DO you know what should i do with this?                                           android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: language_japaneseea (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT language_japaneseea, language_tagalog, language_definition FROM japanesebaybayin WHERE language_japaneseea='arigato';

Comment: It is exactly as the message states. The column you are trying to read does not exist in the table you are trying to read from.

Comment: Hey Kuffs sorry for annoying you but can you help me what should I do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. It's working now. :) I just install it to another emulator..

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused because every time you start the app, you're trying to create the table in the database. But the whole point of using the database is to store data (regardless of whether your app is running), so that table already exists.

A quick fix is to just do "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS", but a better way is to look into how to use SQLite dbs with Android, specifically the OpenHelper class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Comment: HI I put the "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" that you have said and there's no more logcat message like what i have stated above. But another logcat message shows to me by now and this is: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: language_japaneseea (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT language_japaneseea, language_tagalog, language_definition FROM japanesebaybayin WHERE language_japaneseea='arigato'; hmm Do you know how can I fix this one. I'm just a newbie here

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. It's working now. :) I just install it to another emulator..

Answer (score 0):

OOUUCCH!!! All that plumbing code is not so good. I know that for SQLite is neccesary but you can try ORMLite which is the "Hibernate" implementation for SQLite.

Check my example with use all the crud operations plus a lot more methods with criterias:

https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/AndroidOrmLiteDemo

As I said is just an example app but you can copy and paste and use it at your own risk =D.

Comment: Possibly for a more experienced user but the code suggests she is a beginner and so should understand the basics before starting to use frameworks.